# PHP CGI script in Apache Thrift get error "CGI script exit status 0xff00"

Tags: python, php, cgi, thrift

I'm reading the Learning Apache Thrift book by Krzysztof Rakowski. In chapter 3 (found [[here]](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-apache-thrift)). The author explains how to execute the PHP script in server side with python CGI, but the book was using python2.7, so I did some modification to let it adapt to python3.

I was using "python3 runserver.py" command to run the thrift server side code to start python CGI to run a PHP script.
Then using another terminal to execute the thrift client command "python3 client.py".

**On the server side I see this output**:

```
Starting server on port 8080...
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2022 11:05:17] "POST /MyFirstServer.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2022 11:05:18] CGI script exit status 0xff00
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2022 11:05:18] "POST /MyFirstServer.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2022 11:05:19] CGI script exit status 0xff00
```

**On the client side I see this output:**

```
logged current time to logfile (not waiting for response)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 32, in <module>
    product = client.multiply(number1,number2)
  File "gen-py/myfirst/MyFirstService.py", line 79, in multiply
    return self.recv_multiply()
  File "gen-py/myfirst/MyFirstService.py", line 92, in recv_multiply
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "thrift-0.17.0/lib/py/build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "thrift-0.17.0/lib/py/build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "thrift-0.17.0/lib/py/build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 68, in readAll
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

Here is the code how I run the PHP script in Python CGI ("runserver.py"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
  cgi_directories  = ['/']

print("Starting server on port 8080...")

HTTPServer(('', 8080), Handler).serve_forever()
```

And here is the python "client.py" code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, glob
sys.path.append('gen-py')
sys.path.insert(0, glob.glob('thrift-0.17.0/lib/py/build/lib.*')[0])

from myfirst import MyFirstService

from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import THttpClient
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

from random import randint

try:

    # 'localhost', 8080, '/MyFirstServer.php'
    socket = THttpClient.THttpClient("http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServer.php")
    transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(socket)
    protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    client = MyFirstService.Client(protocol)
    transport.open()

    # calling log method
    client.log("logfile.log")
    print("logged current time to logfile (not waiting for response)")

    # calling multiply method with random parameters
    number1 = randint(1,100)
    number2 = randint(1,100)
    product = client.multiply(number1,number2)
    print('%dx%d=%d' % (number1, number2, product))

    # calling get_log_size method
    print("current size of logfile is: %d Bytes" % client.get_log_size("logfile.log"))

    # calling get_log_size method second time, but this time with wrong parameter
    print("current size of logfile is: %d Bytes" % client.get_log_size("no_such_file.log"))


    transport.close()

except Thrift.TException as e:
    print("Received following error:\n  error code: %d\n  error desc: %s' % (e.error_code, e.error_description)")
```

And here is the PHP server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

define('THRIFT_PHP_LIB', __DIR__.'/thrift-0.17.0/lib/php/lib');
define('GEN_PHP_DIR', __DIR__.'/gen-php');

require_once THRIFT_PHP_LIB.'/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php';

use Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader;

$loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', THRIFT_PHP_LIB);
$loader->registerDefinition('myfirst', GEN_PHP_DIR);
$loader->register();


use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;
use Thrift\Transport\TPhpStream;
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport;

class MyFirstHandler implements \myfirst\MyFirstServiceIf {

    public function log($filename) {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/".$filename, $time."\n", FILE_APPEND);
        error_log("Written " . $time . " to " . $filename);
    }

    public function multiply($number1, $number2) {
        error_log("multiply " . $number1 . " by " . $number2);
        return $number1 * $number2;
    }


    public function get_log_size($filename) {
        $filesize = filesize(__DIR__."/".$filename);
        if ($filesize === false)
            {
                $e = new \myfirst\MyError();
                $e->error_code = 1;
                $e->error_description = "Can't get size information for file " . $filename;
                error_log($e->error_description);
                throw $e;
            }
        error_log("size of log file " . $filename . " is " . $filesize . "B");
        return $filesize;
    } 

};

header('Content-Type', 'application/x-thrift');
echo "\r\n";


$handler = new MyFirstHandler();
$processor = new \myfirst\MyFirstServiceProcessor($handler);

$transport = new TBufferedTransport(new TPhpStream(TPhpStream::MODE_R | TPhpStream::MODE_W));
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport, true, true);

$transport->open();
$processor->process($protocol, $protocol);
$transport->close();
```

As I'm not a PHPer, I thought there was something wrong with this error: "CGI script exit status 0xff00". Please help to locate how this problem came out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that it is due to the thrift class reference of "ThriftClassLoader.php".

In "ThriftClassLoader.php", it refers to '/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php' with the following sentence:

```
require_once THRIFT_PHP_LIB.'/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php';
```

But with the thrift package you downloaded from official site, the path is "/thrift-0.17.0/lib/php/lib/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php".

You should create a folder "Thrift" under "/thrift-0.17.0/lib/php/lib/", and copy all of the lib subfolders and classes into "Thrift", and then it would work.

[image]